# How do I show that f(x) is independent for the variationproblem?

Tags: functions, differential

[image: The variationproblem where f(x) is a reel differential function defined in the interval [0,1]]

The variationproblem where f(x) is a reel differential function defined in the interval [0,1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Euler–Lagrange equation:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}
$$
In your case
$$
L = -x^2 - \dot x^2 + f(x)\dot x
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\big(-2\dot x + f(x)\big) = -2x + \frac{df}{dx}\dot x
\\\Longrightarrow -2\ddot x + \frac{df}{dx}\dot x = -2x + \frac{df}{dx}\dot x
\\\Longrightarrow \ddot x = x
$$

Or, you can see that
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\dot x\,dt = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
$$
is a constant.